# kinect not connecting even though powered on and green light

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a kinect xbox360 with hydro on ubuntu 12.04.  I have installed openni and openni-tracker.

The kinect is plugged in and powered on (blinking green light). When running `lsusb`, I do not see the expected three Microsoft devices

`Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp.    Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp.    Bus 002 Device 007: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp.`

When running `lsusb -t`, I do see a device, with device ID that changes when plugging in/ unplugging the kinect (I also see a different device ID when plugging in a USB drive to test...).
I thought it might be a permissions issue, so I've added my user name to the "dialout" group `sudo adduser username` dialout and logged out... without a change in behaviour.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.
Ninja EDIT:
This Kinect was working fine yesterday... I currently have Hydro installed on a removable hotswappable drive and am trying to use this on a different "tower" although the hard-drive is the same...

EDIT;

Issue resolved.  It turns out that the USB ports on the front and back of my PC tower were not supplying enough power... even with the Kinect's power supply.  Using a powered USB hub between the Kinect and the USB ports did the trick.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232290/kinect-not-connecting-even-though-powered-on-and-green-light/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2016-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-20**:
@joe.s: I'd recommend posting your edit as a an answer and then accepting your own answer. That makes the fact that this issue is resolved much more clear when only looking at the question list.

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2016-04-20**:
fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue resolved. It turns out that the USB ports on the front and back of my PC tower were not supplying enough power... even with the Kinect's power supply. Using a powered USB hub between the Kinect and the USB ports did the trick.

---

Originally posted by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) with karma: 162 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1